# How can I change content of several files according to their directory name?

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I have several directories `9.[0-9]15` with a file `file1` which has content like:

```
#/9.015/file1
blah
9.015 blah
blah 9.01577 blah
blah
```

I've copied this `file1` to all directories. I'd like to modify this file from every directory according to the name of the directory they are in. So that `/9.115/file1` is:

```
#/9.115/file1
blah
9.115 blah
blah 9.11577 blah
blah
```

And so on. I know I have to use a regex group to find and modify the part I'd like, but I don't know how to cycle trough that file of every directory while using the directory name as the replacement on the file.

Comment: How to cycle through? `for` loop with glob. How to replace? `sed 's/pattern/repl/'`.

Comment: By the way, I don't think you need regex here. A literal replace is enough, as seen from your example.

Comment: You said that you already created the dirs and copied the files, but given the format of both it seems that it would be more straightforward to just create everything in a loop (unless your question is a simplification for illustrative purposes); e.g: `for n in {0..9}; do DIR=9.${n}15; mkdir $DIR; echo -e "blah\n$DIR blah\nblah $DIR blah\nblah" > $DIR/file; done`

Comment: @Darragh the file is more complex than that, so it would be very large to explicitly put it there, also, there are four more files in each directory (`file1` is the only one that needs changing). thanks for that code, I'd just have to replace the `echo` with a reference to the file and something to modify it.

Comment: @Darragh, @4ae1e1, @Hln, Thank you. I didn't know very well how `for`, `do`, `sed` worked, after looking at your examples it was much easier to figure out. I did it like this, `for i in {0..9}; do dir=9.${i}15; mkdir $dir; sed "s/\(9\.[0-9]15\)/$dir/" file1 > $dir/file1; done`

Comment: Fair enough! I suspected that your actual example was more complicated - just a thought :)

Comment: @4ae1e1 isn't the `pattern` in `sed` a regex?

Comment: @izxle Well technically yes, but I'd rather not call it regex when there's no meta char at all. Also, for any serious regex usage you usually want to enabled extended regex via the `-r` option, otherwise the syntax is just very cumbersome.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for i in 9.[0-9]15/file1 ; do d=`echo $i|sed 's/^\(9\.[0-9]15\).*/\1/'` ; sed -i $i -e "s/9.015/$d/" ; done
```

Here I use `echo` and `sed` to get the necessary part of filename.

As @4ae1e1 mentioned in comments below, you can use parameter expansion instead of `echo` + `sed`: `d=${i%/*}`. More on parameter expansion see [in documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

As for me, the syntax of expansions is quite hard to remember :( And IMHO for *ad hoc* one shot one-liner it's OK to make some "unnecessary" forks.

And yes, it's a good idea to use readable variable names.

Comment: `for` syntax is wrong; not bash syntax. Also, don't abuse `sed` when a simple parameter expansion is enough: `dir=${file%/*}`, where I'm using `dir` and `file` as variable names to be readable. Forks are expansive.

Comment: (Also, even if you want to fork, forking once is better than twice: use `dirname`. Moreover, backticks are deprecated and they usually don't play well with quotes; use `$()` for command substitution.)

Comment: Thank you! I expanded my answer a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it thanks to the help I recieved here.

`$ for dir in $(echo *); do cd $dir; sed -i "s/9.015/$dir/g" file1; cd ..; done`